# How to setup 2 way SSL between 2 node js server or between node js server and tomcat

Tags: node.js, ssl

I would like to setup 2 way SSL between 2 Node.js server. OR between nodejs server and tomcat server.

In my case, I have a backend server is tomcat where it only accepts valid SSL client requests (clientAuth="true"). My node js server acts as a client to backend tomcat server. When clientauth=false then everything works fine, but when clientauth=true then connection fails to establish.

I have enable logs at backend server, I can see empty certificate received from node js so certificate chain is missing so trust is not established and connection fails.

Can anyone help me to understand how to supply node js own certificate(which is client certificate in this case) to backend server.

I am using self sign certificates for this test, all these are available in appropriate certificate stores.

```
12:57:33,477 INFO  [STDOUT] upcoming handshake states: server finished[20]
12:57:33,477 INFO  [STDOUT] *** Certificate chain
12:57:33,477 INFO  [STDOUT] <Empty>
12:57:33,477 INFO  [STDOUT] ***
12:57:33,477 INFO  [STDOUT] Thread-34, fatal error: 42: null cert chain
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain
12:57:33,478 INFO  [STDOUT] %% Invalidated:  [Session-10, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
12:57:33,478 INFO  [STDOUT] Thread-34
12:57:33,478 INFO  [STDOUT] , SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:
12:57:33,478 INFO  [STDOUT] fatal,
12:57:33,478 INFO  [STDOUT] description = bad_certificate
12:57:33,478 INFO  [STDOUT] Thread-34, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
```

Basically tomcat host my REST and nodejs server access those REST endpoints. I am using standard https library at nodejs.

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/chain.pem"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("/ca.pem")
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, host, () => {
```

SSL validation doing only for servers. There is no client directly connects to backend server only other servers can access it. All CA certificates are properly installed in backend truststore.

Comment: What is the client you are using to connect to tomcat? standard http library or axios?  Could you post the nodejs connection script here as well? As you are using self signed certs, you have to use the same CA root cert to sign the certificates that should be generated for nodejs server as well. Also for ssl validation are you using only the server validations? or is it server and client both?

Comment: Basically tomcat host my REST and nodejs server access those REST endpoints. I am using standard https library at nodejs.  const https = require('https');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("/key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("/chain.pem"),
  ca: fs.readFileSync("/ca.pem")
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, host, () => {   SSL validation doing only for servers. There is no client directly connects to backend server only other servers can access it. All CA certificates are properly installed in backend truststore.

Comment: Other tomcat server is able to connect backend server over 2 way ssl. Backend trust-store holds correct set of CA certificates

Comment: What you have added here is using standard https library in node as a server. Post the https client script where you are trying to connect to tomcat server in nodejs.

Comment: Something like this.. const request = require('request'); ....................................new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.post(
            {
                url: url,
                headers: header,
                body: body,
                json: json,
                time: true
            },

Comment: Did you get it resolved? @kedardeshmukh